# How do applications keep track of variable location in RAM?

Tags: variables, location, ram

I have been wondering for a while, but I haven't been able to find an answer. When you write a program, typically you have a few variables. But sometimes these variables are loaded into RAM then unloaded from RAM multiple times, with other variables being added and removed in between.

This just got me thinking, how does the application keep track of where each variable is? I can't be alone in wondering this, and if anyone has an answer I'd love to know.